# How is coexponential defined?

Tags: category-theory

From *Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists*

> Let $C$ be a category with all binary products and let $A$ 
>   and $B$ be objects of $C$. An object $B^A$ is an exponential object if there is 
>   an arrow $eval_{AB}  : (B^A  \times A)  \to  B$ such that for any object $C$ and arrow 
>   $g: (C \times A)\to B$ there is a unique arrow $curry(g): C \to B^A$ such that 
>   $eval_{AB} \circ(curry(g)  \times id_A) =g$.
>
> [image]

How is its dual concept "coexponential" defined?

By reversing the three arrows in the diagram, according to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object

> Dually, a coexponential object in CC is an exponential object in the opposite category C opC^{op}.

?

Thanks.

Comment: Co-X (and $X^{op}$) mean that we keep objects and composition the same, but formally reverse the arrows.

Comment: Reversing the arrows doesn't give you the co-exponential in the "exponential in the opposite category" sense. For that, you also need to turn the products into *coproducts*.